# Web page with ssl certs serve over http 443

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

I have a machine with ubuntu xenial, apache and several vhost, each with its domain.conf and domain-ssl.conf. Each domain.conf redirects to domain-ssl.conf with ssl certs, but the problem is that it throws an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error in chrome because it tries to serve an encrypted web through port 443, that is, apache is trying to serve the ssl webs through http.

The funny thing is that if I access http://example.com:443 shows the web fine, but with https no. By the way, I have the ssl module enabled in apache and I have also tried the  condition and it remains the same.

example.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin development@example.com

    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/example

    SetEnv ENV stage

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/html/example">
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted

            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    Options -MultiViews
                    RewriteEngine On
                    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
                    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
            </IfModule>
    </Directory>
```

example-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin development@example.com

    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/example

    SetEnv ENV stage

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/example/var/logs/apache-ssl.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/example/var/logs/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

    <Directory "/var/www/html/example">
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted

            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
            RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    </Directory>...
```

Exit apachectl -S:

```
user@myserver:~$ sudo apachectl -S
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/010-example-ssl.conf:1)
         port 443 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/010-example-ssl.conf:1)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/015-example.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

options-ssl-apache.conf

```
# Intermediate configuration, tweak to your needs
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off

SSLOptions +StrictRequire

# Add vhost name to log entries:
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common
```

Comment: Please run `apachectl -S` and include output. (And thank you for using `example.com` as your example domain instead of making something up!)

Comment: Perhaps you must also provide the contents of: /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf and whatever other server config SSL configuration you are using. Plus testing with curl , like "curl -Ik https://yourip" to discard you DNS is pointing you somewhere else too.

Comment: I added the file output @ezra-s and tried curl -lk and it returns the index of the server.

Comment: Please show the `Listen` directives in your apache config (`grep -R Listen /etc/apache2/*`)

Comment: I'll be offline for a while, so I'll share my suspicion: I assume you have `Listen 443 http` in your config. This forces http on that port. You either have to change this to `Listen 443 https` or just omit the protocol, https is the default for port 443.

Comment: `user@myserver:/etc/letsencrypt$ grep -R Listen /etc/apache2/*
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:Listen 80
/etc/apache2/ports.conf: Listen 443
/etc/apache2/ports.conf: Listen 443` @GeraldSchneider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I created the `default-ssl.conf` file, which was missing and I enabled it with `sudo a2ensite default-ssl`. Fixed the problem!